# Perl woes - assigning and returning a hashes

Tags: perl

I have an instance variable, properties, that is being declared and instantiated like so:

```
 $self->{properties}{$key1} = $value;
```

My understanding that this will declare the properties field, and also set it to a Hash primitive, containing one key value pair.

I'm trying to write a getter for the properties instance variable, that will return the hash:

```
sub getProperties{
    my $self = shift;

    my %myhash = $self->{properties}; 
    return %myhash;
}
```

And subsequently call the getter like so:

```
my %properties = $properties->getProperties();
```

When I try to compile this i get:

```
"Odd number of elements in hash assignment at 70..."

line 70 being:    my %myhash = $self->{properties};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this line of code:

```
my %myhash = $self->{properties};
```

%myhash is a hash whereas $self->{properties} is a hash *reference*. So you're effectively returning a hash with one key/value pair where the key is a reference to a hash and the value is undef.

If you really want to return a hash, do this:

```
my %myhash = %{$self->{properties}};
```

Alternatively, return a hash reference. That's generally preferable to returning a hash, since it doesn't make a copy of the original hash and therefore is more memory efficient as the hash gets larger. Here's how it looks:

```
sub getProperties {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{properties};
}
```

Then in your calling code instead of this:

```
my %properties = $properties->getProperties();
$somevalue = $properties{'somekey'};
```

do this:

```
# getProperties returns a reference, so assign to a scalar
# variable ($foo) rather than a hash (%foo)
my $properties = $properties->getProperties();

# Use -> notation to dereference the hash reference
$somevalue = $properties->{'somekey'};
```

Comment: Simon if i returned a hash ref like you say - i can later get a hash ref by doing this? 

my %associations = %{$properties->getProperties()};

Comment: That code is fine, and it'll give you a hash (which I think is what you mean :)).

Answer (score 2):

isn't `$self->{properties}` a hashref not a hash?

```
$ perl t4.pl
size -> 42
```

t4.pl

```
#!/usr/bin.perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use t4;

my $t4 = t4->new();
my %hash = $t4->getProperties();
for my $key (keys %hash) {
  print "$key -> $hash{$key}\n";
}
```

t4.pm

```
package t4;

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = {};
  $self->{properties}{size} = 42;
  bless ($self, $class);
}

sub getProperties {
  my $self = shift;
  my %myhash = %{$self->{properties}};
  return %myhash;
}

1;
```